# How can I write a trigger that updates rows in the same table, before the insert is commited?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table in my database called stockpricehistory, which tracks price changes for items of stock, and contains the following feilds:

- Stock ID
- Price
- DateStart (when that particular price was introduced)
- DateEnd(When that particular price stopped being used).

DateStart defaults to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, and DateEnd defaults to nothing, as if there is no DateEnd value, then the price in that row is the current one, for that item of stock.

Now, how can I (I presume it's via a trigger) make it so that whenever I insert a new row for a particular item of stock, it updates the last current row for that item of stock (i.e. the row that matches that item of stock, where DateEnd is set to NULL) to match the DateStart value just given for the new row to be inserted, as follows:

This is the initial state of the table:

1. 1,2.99,2013-11-19 18:49:24,NULL

Then, when the new row is inserted for that item of Stock (ID 1), this is the result:

1. 1,4.99,2013-11-20 12:00:00,NULL
2. 1,2.99,2013-11-19 18:49:24,2013-11-20 12:00:00

In theory, it should only need to update one row, as only one row for each stock ID would be without an end date, which would be the row with the current price.

I presume it would be done via a BEFORE INSERT trigger, but I'm most likely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Filipe Silva said, you can't modify a table in a trigger that is invoked on that table.

You can work around this by having separate tables for the stock and for the stock price history, which is probably a good idea in any case.  The `stock` table holds one row per stock item, along with its current price, and triggers on that table maintain the records in `stockpricehistory` as rows in `stock` are inserted or updated.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55c626/1

```
create table stock (
  stockId int primary key,
  price numeric(5, 2));

create table stockpricehistory (
  stockId int,
  price numeric(5,2),
  dateStart datetime,
  dateEnd datetime);

create trigger t_si before insert on stock
for each row
  insert into stockpricehistory values (new.stockId, new.price, current_timestamp, null);

create trigger t_su before update on stock
for each row begin
  update 
    stockpricehistory 
  set
    dateEnd = current_timestamp
  where
    stockId = new.stockId and
    dateEnd is null;
  insert into stockpricehistory values (new.stockId, new.price, current_timestamp, null);
end;
```

Comment: i'd upvote you if I had the reputation, thanks so much :) That one is much better, i'd initally been persuaded to keep all pricing out of the stock table, and keep it all in the price history table, but having the current price only in the stock table works fine for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

You can always do that update after the insert from the place you do the insert.

To update it you could do:

```
UPDATE stockpricehistory s
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT stockID,
    MAX(dateStart) AS maxDate
  FROM stockpricehistory
  WHERE StockID = 1
    AND DateEnd IS NULL
  ) a ON s.StockID = a.StockID    
SET s.dateEnd = a.maxDate
WHERE s.DateEnd IS NULL
  AND s.dateStart != a.maxDate
```

This is to let you UPDATE one of the rows that has dateEnd NULL, but not the one that has the max(dateStart).

Hope it helps.