# MySQL ON UPDATE trigger - update the same table with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and condition

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp, conditional-statements

I have a MySQL(5.1.67) table '**tracker**' with TIMESTAMP field '**close_time**'.
In the same table I have string field '**status**'.
I want to update **close_time** field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP value when **status** field updated to specific text value, for example '*Closed*'.

Here is sample with INSERT:
[How can I write a trigger that updates rows in the same table, before the insert is commited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079686/how-can-i-write-a-trigger-that-updates-rows-in-the-same-table-before-the-insert)

I tried something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `close_time_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tracker` FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
     IF NEW.status = 'Closed' THEN
     SET NEW.close_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;     
     END IF;
     END
```

But I got error: You have an error in your SQL syntax ... at line 4.

I tried some other variations which I found but none of them works.
Please help to create correct trigger for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the `DELIMITER`?

This should work:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `close_time_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tracker` FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
     IF NEW.status = 'Closed' THEN
     SET NEW.close_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;     
     END IF;
     END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

you didn't tell it what to update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `close_time_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tracker` FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
     IF NEW.status = 'Closed' THEN
       update tracker 
         SET NEW.close_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
     END IF;
   END
```

Comment: What do you mean? I want to create trigger on UPDATE event. Here is a sample with "before update" and "new": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: my bad, I missed that.  before update works, but after would too.  i think your update statement is wrong.  i will edit my answer

Comment: you need to change you delimiter.  add this line to the top of your script: delimiter//  and the last line will be end//